# Solver for Pareto Inventory on Excel

Tags: excel, inventory, pareto-chart

Hi have two columns on excel with data like this one:

[image]

The first column represents a counter of a specific item in an inventory data sheet, and the second one represents the cumulative percentage of usage for that specific inventory.

The deal is to find the A-B-C classification for logistics analysis.

Right now, the procedure followed for its classification is the following:

- Draw of a dispersion graph on excel
- Draw of a line from one corner to another
- Draw of a line from the upper corner until it reaches the dispersion
- We move the duplication of that line until it touches the dispersion and the line

[image]

The lower intersection marks the start of category "B" items, the upper intersection marks the category "C" items (A10 is the cell on excel, and so it is A65).

There is a way of do this study without the graphical aid? Thanks!

Comment: You should look at [this site](https://exceltable.com/en/analyses-reports/abc-xyz-analysis-in-excel) and [this one](https://abcsupplychain.com/abc-analysis/) that may give you some direct help.